# aligning columns and rows to match display width

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to create a table-like layout with columns and rows using flex.

It looks ok, but I can't figure out how to push the buttons over to the right side of the screen...they just kind of stay there in the middle.

Here is my code + styles for one of the rows(they all use the same style):

```
<View style={{  flex: 1,    flexDirection: 'column',    justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                        <View style={{  flex: 1,  flexDirection: 'row',  justifyContent: 'space-between',  maxHeight: 40 }}>
                            <View>
                                <Image  source={character.Avatar}  />
                            </View>
                            <View style={{    width: 100, height: 50,  marginTop: 5}}>
                                <Button />
                            </View> 
                        </View>
                </View>
```

Below is what it looks like on screen. How can I get the buttons on the right, to line up on the right side of the screen?

thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy!
Just add `alignItems: 'flex-end'` in your parent of `Button`, like this :

`<View style={{width: 100, height: 50, marginTop: 5, alignItems: 'flex-end'}}>
   <Button />
 </View>`

I test this on my emulator , hope it works for you